# how to assign hexadecimal color code in primarySwatch in flutter?

Tags: flutter

i would like to insert an hexadecimal color code in the primarySwatch property, here is what i have tried to do :

```
           return MaterialApp(
             title: 'Login Demo',
             theme: ThemeData(
              // brightness: Brightness.dark,
               primarySwatch: Color(0xFF3399FF),
```

Comment: PrimarySwatch is not a Color, but a MaterialColor, a class with a primary color and a Map of shades. 
 https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialColor-class.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This [tutorial](https://medium.com/@filipvk/creating-a-custom-color-swatch-in-flutter-554bcdcb27f3) shows a function that can build primarySwatches from a `Color`.

```dart
MaterialColor buildMaterialColor(Color color) {
  List strengths = <double>[.05];
  Map<int, Color> swatch = {};
  final int r = color.red, g = color.green, b = color.blue;

  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    strengths.add(0.1 * i);
  }
  strengths.forEach((strength) {
    final double ds = 0.5 - strength;
    swatch[(strength * 1000).round()] = Color.fromRGBO(
      r + ((ds < 0 ? r : (255 - r)) * ds).round(),
      g + ((ds < 0 ? g : (255 - g)) * ds).round(),
      b + ((ds < 0 ? b : (255 - b)) * ds).round(),
      1,
    );
  });
  return MaterialColor(color.value, swatch);
}
```

Then in the theme you can do:

```dart
      primarySwatch: buildMaterialColor(Color(0xFF3399FF)),
```

Comment: in case anyone get Error: The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<int, Color>', try to change the line: Map swatch = <int, Color>{}; to: Map<int, Color> swatch = {};

Answer (score 1):

You can set primarySwatch property like below.

```
Map<int, Color> color =
{
50:Color.fromRGBO(51, 153, 255, .1),
100:Color.fromRGBO(51, 153, 255, .2),
200:Color.fromRGBO(51, 153, 255, .3),
300:Color.fromRGBO(51, 153, 255, .4),
400:Color.fromRGBO(51, 153, 255, .5),
500:Color.fromRGBO(51, 153, 255, .6),
600:Color.fromRGBO(51, 153, 255, .7),
700:Color.fromRGBO(51, 153, 255, .8),
800:Color.fromRGBO(51, 153, 255, .9),
900:Color.fromRGBO(51, 153, 255, 1),
};
...
primarySwatch: MaterialColor(0xFF3399FF, color)
```

Comment: i got an error, i would like to use one color, but it seems in your example you are merge alla these colors with mine or what?

Comment: Do you type '...' characters?
Anyway it is similar you selected answer.
'51, 153, 255' is RGB values what you want(0xFF3399FF).

Answer (score 1):

MaterialColor requires shades. So you need a function like:

```
MaterialColor getMaterialColor() {
  int colorValue = 0xFFC9F5FC;
  Color color = Color(colorValue);
  Map<int, Color> shades = [50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900]
      .asMap()
      .map((key, value) => MapEntry(value, color.withOpacity(1 - (1 - (key + 1) / 10))));

  return MaterialColor(colorValue, shades);
}
```

or you can use it as extension like:

```
extension ToMaterialColor on Color {
  MaterialColor get asMaterialColor {
    Map<int, Color> shades = [50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900]
        .asMap()
        .map((key, value) => MapEntry(value, withOpacity(1 - (1 - (key + 1) / 10))));

    return MaterialColor(value, shades);
  }
}
...
primarySwatch: Color(0xFFC9F5FC).asMaterialColor
```